# I want to build a code to recognize some information from a form picture with tensorflow

Tags: image, tensorflow, nlp

Can someone introduce some guide about this question? I have looking tutorial from official site of tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-classification-in-10-minutes-with-mnist-dataset-54c35b77a38d) is a good example for recognising digits from a picture. It is in keras which is also supported by TensorFlow.

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/keras/basic_classification) is another tutorial for recognizing clothes from pictures.